# Create a js array of objects from array value

Tags: javascript

I'm retrieving some array values and i would like to convert them into an array of objects.

```
const allActiveUnits = data.map((activeUnit) => activeUnit.fields.assetKey);

// returns an Array [ "CF-KEY123", "ABC-123" ]
```

I've tried using Object.fromEntries as seen below.

```
const createObj = Object.fromEntries(
  allActiveUnits.map(unit => [unit, {
    id: unit,
    checked: false
  }])
)
```

But returns...

```
{
  "CF-KEY123": {
    "id": "CF-KEY123",
    "checked": false
  },
  "ABC-123": {
    "id": "ABC-123",
    "checked": false
  }
}
```

I would like to transform this into an array full of objects as seen below.

e.g.

```
  [
    {
      name: "CF-KEY123",
      id: "CF-KEY123",
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      name: "ABC-123",
      id: "ABC-123",
      checked: false,
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Your goal is an array. `Object.fromEntries` creates an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is an array. `Object.fromEntries` creates an object. You can remove it and directly create the structure of the object in the `map` call:

```js
const allActiveUnits = [ "CF-KEY123", "ABC-123" ];
const createObj = allActiveUnits.map(unit => ({
    name: unit,
    id: unit,
    checked: false
  }));
  
console.log(createObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const object = {
  'CF-KEY123': {
    id: 'CF-KEY123',
    checked: false,
  },
  'ABC-123': {
    id: 'ABC-123',
    checked: false,
  },
};
const arrayOfObject = Object.entries(object).map(([key, val]) => ({ name: key, ...val }));

console.log(arrayOfObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

  const newArr = myArray.map((item) => {
    return { name: item, id: item, checked: false };
  });

 console.log(newArr);
```

result -

```
[
    {
      name: "one",
      id: "one",
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      name: "two",
      id: "two",
      checked: false,
    },
  ]
```

Here is what you looking for :)